# How to allow registered users to change their user role through frontend?

Tags: user-roles, front-end, upgrade

From time to time i want to give my registered users the chance to upgrade their user role by themselves for free. I tried this by writing a little plugin, but sady i can't get the html form to show when using the shortcode, and therefore cant test if it works or not. I would be really thankful for any assistance.

```
function upgrade_to_premium() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( is_page( 'upgrade-to-premium' ) ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if( $current_user->roles[0] == "subscriber" || $current_user->roles[0] == "premium" ) {
                $user_id = $current_user->id;
                $role = $current_user->roles[0];
                if( $_POST['role']){
                    if( $_POST['role'] == $role ) {
                        echo "Sorry, you are already a " . $role . "!";
                    } else {
                        $role = $_POST['role'];
                        $userdata = array();
                        $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
                        $userdata['role'] = $role;
                        wp_update_user($userdata);
                        echo "Your user type has been changed!  You are now a " . $role . "!";
                    }
                }
                ?>

                    <form method="post" action="">
                        Please select a role:<br/>
                        <select name="role">
                            <option value="subscriber" selected="selected">Subscriber</option>
                            <option value="premium">Premium</option>
                        </select>
                        <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" />
                    </form>

                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'upgrade_to_premium', 'upgrade_to_premium' );
```

Comment: shortcodes should return their output, not echo it

Comment: See updated answer. thanks Mark. JulesB one thing is that you should never trust the user input, example if you allow editing the role via a simple $_POST select element, the user can manipulate the value in browser to get admin role for example. so you have to check if the value sent to php via $_POST is acceptable/within your secure range of values before processing it. In your code sample, I can easily inject 'administrator' as role and get role priv. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the code a bit and this works on my localhost. Try it and let me know if it does the job.

**Be careful to edit your own admin role though.** Or put in another condition to prevent updating your admin role in case of a use error.

**Edit: added ob_start()** thanks to Mark Kaplun. Shortcodes need to be returned not echoed.

```
add_shortcode( 'upgrade_to_premium', 'upgrade_to_premium' );
function upgrade_to_premium() {

    // Stop if user is not logged in.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    ob_start();

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        Please select a role:<br/>
        <select name="role">
            <option value="subscriber" selected="selected">Subscriber</option>
            <option value="premium">Premium</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

    <?php

    // Do not process anything if it's not $_POST
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['role'] ) )
        return;

    // Never trust user input.
    $role = sanitize_key( $_POST['role'] );
    if ( ! in_array( $role, array( 'subscriber', 'premium' ) ) )
        return;

    // Get the user object
    $user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
    $index = key( $user->roles );
    $user_role = $user->roles[ $index ];

    // User already got that user
    if ( $user_role == $role ) {

        echo sprintf( __( 'You already have %s role.' ), $role );

    } else {

        // update user role
        $user->set_role( $role );
        echo sprintf( __( 'Your role was changed to %s.' ), $role );

    }

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed Mahdi, first of all thanks for the quick reply. Your code looks a lot cleaner than mine and i'm sure that it would work, but i still can't get the form to be displyed when using the shortcode `[upgrade_to_premium]`? Any ideas what this could be caused by?

Comment: you're welcome. ok lets try this: 1. go to a new page 2. add the shortcode [upgrade_to_premium] publish page 3. view the page as logged in. In theme's functions.php put the code in my answer as is. If you can't see the form after these steps please let me know. basically the form should appear if the shortcode was added correctly (the only requirement is that you need to be logged-in)

Comment: If this worked as a solution, please do not forget to make it as "accepted answer" thank you

Comment: @ahmed-fouad Thank you, this is working for me, but any idea how to correctly add a 'selected' to the select option that contains the users current role? I have tried adding `<option value="subscriber"<?php if ( in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) : ?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>Subscriber</option>`

and added `clean_user_cache( $user );` after the set_role, but the selected option is not correct unless I refresh the page again after submit