# Allow user to select role from front end edit profile form

Tags: user-roles, front-end

I have a front end edit profile form working fine (thanks to [previous answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end))

I'm having trouble adding a form element that lets the user change their role.

I've tried adding:

```
                        <label for="user-role">Role</label>
                        <input class="user-role" name="user-role" type="text" id="user-role" value="contributor" />
                    </p><!-- .form-user-role -->
```

together with -

```
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wp-capabilities', esc_attr( $_POST['user-role'] ) );
```

or

```
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'role', esc_attr( $_POST['user-role'] ) );
```

and various things like -

```
$u = new WP_User( $current_user->ID );

// Remove role
$u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

// Add role
$u->add_role( 'contributor' );

OR 

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user->set_role('contributor');

OR 

update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wp_capabilities', 'contributor', true );
update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wp_capabilities', array( 'contributor' => 1 ) );
}
```

Still no luck, obviously I'm not quite grasping this. Can role not be set in the same way as the other fields?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$current_user->set_role()` should work because WordPress also sets the user's role that way. But if it doesn't work for you, try calling [`clean_user_cache()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/clean_user_cache/) after changing the user's role.

Comment: Thank you @SallyCJ, that didn't seem to help, although I'm not sure I implemented it correctly (it was in a page template rather than functions.php / a plugin, not sure if this affects it)

Nevertheless, I seem to have got the functionality I needed using this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240230/how-to-allow-registered-users-to-change-their-user-role-through-frontend